# GPOs not applying to Windows 10 since Update

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, windows-10-v1709

i've got a strange problem:

i've got a Windows 2008 Domain with several clients (XP, 7, Server 2008, 10). Since i've updated some of the Windows 10 clients to version 1709 (Fall Creators Update) the most of the GPOs aren't applied to the clients anymore (no matter where they are linked). On any other client they work fine.

[image: the GPOs don't have a WMI-Filter or anything]

Comment: Have you tried running gpupdate /force? Is the dns setup correctly? Is the pc a member of the domain? If you run gpresult /v does it show the policies being applied?

Comment: yes, i've tried gpupdate /force, the dns setup is correct  and the pc is member of the domain. if i run gpresult /v it doesn't show up the Object

Comment: If it doesn't show up the object, then move the object to the top-most level in your forest and make them apply on subfolders too. I had a similar problem of a GPO not being affected because it was not in the root of my domain.

Comment: Originally the GPO was linked to the domain root, but no matter where i link it, it still won't show up on the client, even not if i link it to the direct OU of the client

Comment: It should be linked in the root, then you apply a gpupdate /force then a gpresult /v to verify that it worked. Once the GPO object shows up at gpresult, you can verify other problems if they still exists. Consider creating a new GPO object just to test if that works.

Comment: Now i've created a new GPO for testing and linked it to the domain root. On the clients running not running windows 10 1709 it shows up, but not on the windows 10 clients :-/

Comment: This is weird. I'm afraid I have no idea what this can be caused by.

Comment: I've found a solution for this problem, the GPOs that weren't applied contained scheduled tasks, which were binded to a user-session. To solve this problem, the authority has to been set to SYSTEM

Comment: Nice. You should post that as an answer, so you can accept it, and others know you no longer need help. It also makes searching for the answer far easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer:

Since an update Microsoft doesn't accept GPOs with scheduled tasks binded to a user session. To solve this problem, the authority has to been set to SYSTEM.[image]